# Projecting 3D Model onto 2d plane

Tags: python, 3d, computer-vision, projection

I have a 3d object, and wish to export it in all direction.Suppose I have home picture and if I project it on 2d plane it only show me something like square but if I change angle it give me different view(In short I want different 2d projection of same 3d object for better visualization).I am looking for python library or algorithm which able to do that.Please ref diagram to get clear idea what i want.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQojf.png)

Comment: I am looking for python code.

Comment: Welcome! There are plenty of libraries that do that kind of stuff. Anyway, your question is unclear and lacks any effort whatsoever. This will probably be heavily downvoted if left in that sorry state.

Comment: Actually I want to project 3D model onto 2D plane. Please refer fig.1 of of this paper https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/087d/87eb6fc37245b7867cde27235c2f23574949.pdf  You will get an idea what actually I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with the projective transformation. This are actually just two matrix multiplication and one division. Might be written in one line of Python.
[image]

The vector on the right is one of your many 3D vertices of the 3D model. The matrix [r_11 ... t_3] is a rigid transformation and represents the location and orientation of your plane (some people call it camera pose or extrinsic camera parameters). This matrix you are going to change for each individual projection. The matrix [f_x ... 1] defines the projection itself and remains usually unchanged. With your application, it might be possible to just use the identity matrix (therefore, you could ignore it). The last step is scaling the transformed vector in the way, that it lays on the image plane in a distance of z = 1. u_x and u_y are your corresponding 2D coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I just edited my question for clear understanding.Sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Its seem like perspective projection but I want orthographic projection

Comment: The orthographic projection is easy to compute. You only need the two right components of above transformation. Of the resulting vector of [r_11 ... t_3] * [A_x; A_y; A_z], just set the z-component to zero.

Comment: I have no knowledge of computer graphics I understood what you said but can you please explain little bit above matrix what fx and fy etc.

Comment: I'm looking precisely for something like that, did you write a code ? How do you define the matrix R given the angle of the view and the distance from the object ?

Comment: @ Armand: In python, matrix & vector multiplication is available in numpy. To get a spacial transformation matrix (rotations, translations) you can use the package transforms3d https://pypi.org/project/transforms3d/  In C++, I use Eigen or OpenCV for matrix & vector arithmetic. With OpenCV you can create easily transformation matrices too.