# 3D to 2D projection about horizontal midplane

Tags: 3d, projection

I would like to project a 3d box on a 2d horizontal midplane. I have an understanding of what perspective projection is. I referred the below link.

https://amycoders.org/tutorials/3dbasics.html

But how do you compute x and y coordinates about midplane? This is not clear to me. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you also need an advice about what language to use? Is it for a proof of concept, homework or heavy computing on gigantic datasets?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008483/numpy-fastest-3d-to-2d-projection and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849117/projecting-3d-model-onto-2d-plane

Comment: Your question is unclear; the page you linked to does not even mention 'midplane'. What do you mean by that? Midplane generally means a plane going through the middle of an object, but if you're trying to get a slice of the object, then that has nothing to do with perspective projection.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn Thanks for the comment. I was able to understand perspective projection from the link I mentioned in my post. But I had some misunderstanding. I wanted a slice of the object about the horizontal midplane and not do any projection of a 3d box on a 2d plane. I resolved this problem though. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @nicolallias for the posts and the links. I was looking for some ideas to plot some isolines in IDL.